# Meteor's Remote Database Connection Timeout and Reconnect

Tags: node.js, meteor

Does Meteor have a setting to timeout and retry if its MongoDB does not give a response in x seconds?  Wondering if anyone has tried this.

I am interested in running a MongoDB database remote to the Meteor production app.  The Meteor-to-Mongo connection will be quick, just 3-9 milliseconds away, but I also want to understand how Meteor (and NodeJS) would react to a brief network outage.  Would the app hang while waiting for a long timeout period?  How can I force a 1 second timeout/retry to avoid a hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify timeout in the mongo URL:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://host:port/db?connectTimeoutMS=60000&socketTimeoutMS=60000
```

but let's say you have a network outage, what does a short timeout give you? 
your app will hang anyways...

To get high availability, look into replica sets.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: Good point. I will look into replica sets...assuming I can specify different read versus write mongo servers?  I believe mongo only allows writes on a single master mongo instance in the replica set.

Comment: mongodb://host1,host2,host3:27017/dev?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primaryPreferred&w=majority&connectTimeoutMS=60000&socketTimeoutMS=60000

Comment: ps: Meteor will crash if it doesn't find the master at first, but if you run it with a process manager it will restart and eventually connect.